# getting a complete list of possible URI in an href attribute

Tags: html, uri, href

The only URI's i know are:

```
javascript:

vbscript:
```

and `data:`
What are the other URI's available in an href attribute?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`a`’s [`href` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/CR-html5-20130806/links.html#attr-hyperlink-href) "must have a value that is a valid URL".

And an URL is [valid](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/CR-html5-20130806/infrastructure.html#valid-url) "if it conforms to the authoring conformance requirements in the URL standard".

It links to the following URL standard: http://url.spec.whatwg.org/

This living standard notes that "A scheme must be registered", but the relevant section is not finished yet ("…"). It’s probably safe to assume that it will refer to IANA’s URI scheme registration: http://www.iana.org/assignments/uri-schemes.html.

So you can use any URI whose scheme is listed in the "URI Scheme" column, as long as the URI conforms to the specification linked in the "Reference" column. Or in other words: if the scheme is not registered there, it’s not an URI.

That said, `javascript` and `vbscript` are not a valid/registered URI schemes, and you are therefore (if the above assumption is correct) not allowed to use them as value for the `href` attribute. However, [`javascript` is defined in the HTML5 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/CR-html5-20130806/webappapis.html#javascript-protocol) and there is also an [expired draft](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-hoehrmann-javascript-scheme-03). So maybe the WHATWG URL standard will have a different definition ("registered, no matter where"? But that would lead to collisions …), or the `javascript` scheme will be registered at IANA (maybe when the HTML5 spec becomes a Recommendation?).

Answer (score 0):

1. Those aren't
   [URIs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_resource_identifier)
2. You
   can have any [URI scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_scheme)
   you want in there, the issue isn't what's allowed but what's supported in the browser viewing the page
3. If you want to register your web app as a handler for a particular URI scheme, [use `registerProtocolHandler`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/navigator.registerProtocolHandler) (but note the support info at the bottom of the page)